# insert result of DataSet to ListView

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, windows-ce

i try to insert result of DataSet to ListView and i got Strange result.

i need to see the result like this:

```
Fname | Lname | Age
===================
AA    | AA1   |  10
BB    | BB1   |  20
CC    | CC1   |  30
DD    | DD1   |  40
```

i try this:

```
SQL = "select Fname,Lname,Age from MyCount";
dsView = new DataSet();
adp = new SqlCeDataAdapter(SQL, Conn_Count);
adp.Fill(dsView, "MyCount");
adp.Dispose();

DataTable dplist = dsView.Tables["MyCount"];
for (int i = 0; i < dplist.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   DataRow drow = dplist.Rows[i];
   ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["Fname"].ToString());
   //lstTasks.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
   lstTasks.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

but i got only one field and i see the result Horizontal like this:

```
AA  BB  CC  DD
```

i work on C# for Windows-CE

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you add these lines too?

```
ListViewItem itemLastName = new ListViewItem(drow["Lname"].ToString());
ListViewItem itemAge = new ListViewItem(drow["Age"].ToString());

lstTasks.Items.Add(itemLastName);
lstTasks.Items.Add(itemAge);
```

Comment: thanks, I tried it and everything looks messy in the table, there isnt  fall in line and no borders

Comment: Can you insert the code block which writes listviewitems to help you more?

Answer (score 0):

A listview can not be data bound :-(

You need to create a string[] array with the 'rows' you like to add and then add this string arry to the listview:

```
foreach(DataColumn thiscol in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    lvItems.Columns.Add(thiscol.ColumnName, 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
}
foreach(DataRow thisrow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    string[] fields = new string[thisrow.ItemArray.Length];
    for(int iCount = 0; iCount < fields.Length; iCount++)
    {
        fields[iCount] = thisrow[iCount].ToString();
    }
    lvItems.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(fields));
}
```

found at http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-databinding-listview-cf-t1298573.html